# docker swam - secrets from file not resolving tilde

Tags: docker-compose, docker-swarm

Using secrets from docker-compose on my dev machine works. But the remote server via ssh just says `open /home/johndoe/~/my-secrets/jenkinsuser.txt: no such file or directory`.

secret definition in `stack.yml`:

```
secrets:
  jenkinsuser:
    file: ~/my-secrets/jenkinsuser.txt
```

Run with:
`docker stack deploy -c stack.yml mystack`

The documentation does not mention any gotchas about ~ path. I am not going to put the secret files inside `.` as all examples do, because that directory is version controlled.
Am I missing some basics about variable expansion, or differences between docker-compose and docker swarm?

Answer (score 1):

Your `~` character in your path is considered as literal. Use `$HOME` wich is treated as a variable in your string path.

Tilde character work only if it is unquoted. In your remote environment, the SWARM yaml parser consider your path as a string, where the prefix-tilde is read as a normal character (see [prefix-tilde](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html)).

Comment: In normal docker compose files the tilde character is also unquoted. The yml file is on the remote server, so appears to be "local" to the shell. Do you have any source about tilde being a string literal, in which contexts?